# Почему перед «слышно было только» ставится запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Наступила тишина, слышно было только; как фыркали и жевали лошади да похрапывали спящие.

Comment: Вы, похоже, не проверили текст перед отправкой.

Comment: Лучше бы про вторую запятую спросить.

Comment: Тишина — это когда ничего не слышно (словарь: *отсутствие **звуков**, говора, шума*). В предложении логическая ошибка.

Comment: У классика нет никакой логической ошибки, как нет и никакой второй запятой. *Наступила тишина. Слышно было только, как фыркали и жевали лошади да похрапывали спящие; где-то не близко плакал один чибис и изредка раздавался писк трех бекасов, прилетавших поглядеть, не уехали ли непрошеные гости...* (А. П. Чехов. Степь). Стругацкие: *Свет на лестнице почему-то не включили, было сумрачно, и стояла тишина, слышно было только, как плещет вода, стекающая с крыши за открытыми окнами*.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Фырканье, жевание, похрапывание, плач и писк — это не тишина. "Только" используется, когда один или два элемента, а там аж четыре. Это как: *Хочу только дом, машину, мотоцикл и ноутбук.* Точка с запятой не подходит для разделения элементов сравнительного оборота, она нарушает синтаксическую связь, да и до этого нет запятых, чтобы усиливать знак. У Розенталя сказано, что между группами ставится просто запятая. Союз "как" надо бы повторить, но "только" это не позволяет. Не делайте из классиков святых.